# I am getting an error AttributeError: module 'pymc' has no attribute 'stochastic_from_dist'

Tags: python, python-import

I have to use **HDDM**, python module but when I've tried to import hddm I'm getting this error: **AttributeError: module 'pymc' has no attribute 'stochastic_from_dist'**

`import hddm`

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kabuki\utils.py in <module>
    310     return pm.flib.cauchy(x, 0, S) + len(x) * np.log(2)
    311 
--> 312 HalfCauchy = pm.stochastic_from_dist(name="Half Cauchy",
    313                                      random=centered_half_cauchy_rand,
    314                                      logp=centered_half_cauchy_logp,

AttributeError: module 'pymc' has no attribute 'stochastic_from_dist'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same error! Were you able to figure this out?